# Setting up two database on oracle

Tags: oracle10g, version, instance

I am using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition on windows.

I want to install two database instance on one system. Both the instance will have similar db structure but are of different version and at one time I'll be using only one instance.

Can anybody help me how can I achive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to install multiple instances on Express Edition.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#BEIEJGGF